# Saving Spark Dataframe to csv has empty rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

LATER EDIT 2: I found the problem, I should normally delete this question as the mistake I made is not related to what I'm asking, the source of the problem was somewhere else. 
There are some nuggets of knowledge in it though so I will leave it unless community decides to take it down.

LATER EDIT: So, not sure why this did not came earlier to me, the solution is to use dataframe.na.drop("all") to get rid of all the empty rows. I would still like to know why they appear though. Other filters do not create these empty lines.

I can't find any answers or hints why this happens. I suspect filter is the culprit but not sure if so, why and how to fix it.

I define a dataframe as a another dataframe filtered based on several conditions.Then I save it as csv:

```
var dataframe = dataframe_raw.filter($"column1" !== $"column2" || $"column3"!==$"column4").drop($"column2").drop($"column4")
dataframe.write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true").csv("hdfs:///path/to/file/")
```

The problem is that the output "part" file(s) contains empty rows. Any ideea why and how to remove them?

Thank you.

Note: also tried coalesce(1) that helps with saving only one file but that also contains empty rows.

Comment: Could columns 1 & 3 be empty in the source(`dataframe_raw`)? That could explain it

Comment: Compare the dataframe you are writing using `dataframe.show`. See where the differences lie and is there any specific pattern to the missing row. Update the question with your findings.

Comment: Columns 1&3 are not empty. I'm not sure why I would get completely empty rows  if they were (there are other columns in the DF that are not empty), can you please describe?

Comment: Compare to? Count and show do not count/display the empty lines, just when writing the csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is related to operators precedence in Scala. To solve this please try changing `!==` to `===`.

```
dataframe_raw.filter($"column1" =!= $"column2" || $"column3"=!=$"column4")
```

Second option is to add parenthesis.

```
dataframe_raw.filter(($"column1" !== $"column2") || ($"column3"!==$"column4"))
```

Comment: Actually I was already using parenthesis, forgot to add them in the original text. I tried changing the order of the operations =!= results in the same thing.

Comment: Can you please show result of operation `dataframe_raw.show()`, without it is hard to say what is wrong if you added parenthesis and tried `=!=`.

Comment: Not sure how to help you here. I can't publish the contents of the dataframe and if mask the data it might become irrelevant for you. If it helps: I join 2 similar dataframes, yesterday and today's results of the same procedure, on 2 common keys, then I compare 4 columns from the new with 4 from the old, keeping those with differences. The columns compared are of type long and string (date as string to be exact). Also, the join is outer, and I keep the results that are in today's result but are not present in yesterday's result.

Comment: I found the mistake, it's from the outer join, I do not filter out the rows that are in right but I delete all the columns that are in right. quite a dumb mistake. I accepted your answer, thanks for the effort.